# requestMapping mistakenly called

Tags: spring-mvc, spring-security, spring-boot

I seem to have a problem configuring spring mvc and spring security as it allways loops inside the controller (trying to get static content)

**SecurityConfiguration.java**

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
@EnableGlobalMethodSecurity(prePostEnabled = true, securedEnabled = true)
class SecurityConfiguration extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

    @Inject
    public UserDetailsService userService;

    @Inject
    public void configureGlobal(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth)throws Exception{
        auth.userDetailsService(userService).passwordEncoder(passwordEncoder());
    }

  /*@Override
  public void configure(WebSecurity web) throws Exception {
    web.ignoring()
      .antMatchers();
  }//*/

  public void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception{
        http
          .csrf().disable()
          .authorizeRequests()
          .antMatchers("/connect/**", "/**/*.{js,css,html}").permitAll()
          .anyRequest().authenticated()
          .and()
          .formLogin()
          .loginPage("/login").permitAll()
          .and().logout()
          .logoutUrl("/logout").permitAll();
    }
}
```

**Controller**

```
@Controller
class Main {
  @RequestMapping(name = "/login",method=RequestMethod.GET)
  public String index(@AuthenticationPrincipal User user):  {
    if(user != null){return "login";/*always enters here after login no matter the url*/}
    else{ return "redirect:/index";}

  }
}
```

The problem is the fact that no matter url(for example /pankackes) i give it tries to use that request mapping(checked with debugger)

**Edit 1**
 didnt mention it but my directory structure allready goes like this

```
src/
  main/
    resources/
      static/
        dist/
        styles/
        jspm_packages/
        index.html
      templates/
        login.html
    java/
      .../
        main.java
        ...
```

Comment: is the problem in forwarding to login always ?

Comment: yes that is the problem, it allways forwards to "/login"

Comment: where is the implementation of login?

Comment: Is spring security default, in the configureGlobal function in SecurityConfiguration.java

Comment: please tell me if it works

Answer (score 0):

move your static files to corresponding folders under resources/static - so your tree would look like

```
src
  main
    resources
      static
        js
        css
        ...
```

those files will be available under your root path like:

```
http://localhost:8080/css/filename.css
```

spring boot will handle permitAll on static files for you.

About */pancakes* - all your paths instead `"/connect/**", "/**/*.{js,css,html}"` are going to be redirected to login site.

Comment: allready had that, look at edit " it goes to the **/login** action when entering **http://localhost:8080/jspm_packages//file.js**"

Answer (score 0):

you missed the authentication-manager implementation, try this as an example, (add them in spring security xml file)

```
<authentication-manager alias="authenticationManager">
        <authentication-provider>
            <user-service>
                <user name="user1" password="user1Pass" authorities="ROLE_USER" />
                <user name="admin1" password="admin1Pass" authorities="ROLE_ADMIN" />
            </user-service>
        </authentication-provider>
    </authentication-manager>
```

or use this:

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
public class HelloWebSecurityConfiguration
   extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

  @Autowired
  public void configureGlobal(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) {
    auth
      .inMemoryAuthentication()
        .withUser("user").password("password").roles("USER");
  }
}
```

Comment: nope, it seems as long as I have @ RequestMapping annotatinons, the static assets dont work, if I delete the @ Controller classes I can access my static files

Comment: but also you did not use login mechanism

Comment: I can login in in the controller in the example 'if(user != null){return "login";} ' it does go in. As for the authenthication the line 'auth.userDetailsService(userService).passwordEncoder(passwordEncoder());' takes care of it.

Comment: Where do you store username and password?

Comment: database, userService checks the database for the username, and returns an implementation of UserDetails

Comment: its something like in this blog post,http://kielczewski.eu/2014/12/spring-boot-security-application/. In the Authentication section

Comment: That's what i am trying to say, you did not mention datasource and authentication manager